# Date format in bash

Tags: linux, bash

Simple bash question... I suppose, I'm new.

I have substract date from system time

```
date_from=`date -d "30 minutes ago"`
```

after, I want format the result in `$date_from`  in 'yyyy-mm-dd'

how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
date -d "30 minutes ago" +%Y-%m-%d
```

It is very likely, though, that 30 minutes ago it was the same day :)

Comment: Thanks!
I know Michael, this is for script running every five minutes on 24h ^_^

Answer (score 4):

You can append a format string:

```
date -d "30 minutes ago" +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

Answer (score -1):

As you can't guarantee that 30 minutes ago would be the same day, your best solution would be convert the current date/time into seconds from 1970, subtract 30*60 seconds, and then convert this back into a date.

I could do this in a script, not sure how to do it in one line.

Something like:

```
CURRENT=date +%S
CURRENTMINUS30=expr $CURRENT - (30*60)
OLD = date -d@`CURRENTMINUS30`
```

That's untested though. I'll have a go at getting the script to work and post it's contents, and perhaps someone else can do it in one line.

Comment: I don't see the need to convert to a UNIX timestamp first. `date` can handle the change in day just fine if necessary.

Comment: Ah OK. Totally misunderstood the other answers. Didn't realise "30 minutes ago" was a valid input for `date`! I just thought they were unfinished answers. Every day's a school day.